# Get a list of epoch timestamps in a date range?

Tags: javascript, epoch

Working on a web app. I do not have the data yet from the web service, but I know the data will include an epoch timestamp. I was wondering if anyone knew of a way to generate consecutive (random) epoch timestamps. I use freedatagenerator for most of my data generating needs, and they have a way of creating epoch timestamps, but not in order. I need hundreds for testing purposes, so i don't really want to go in and do it by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating ones in consecutive order?

```
var myDates = [Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)]; //UTC timestamp in seconds
var maxGap = 60; //our maximum time gap is 60 seconds
for(var i = 0; i<100; i++) {
    myDates.push(myDates[i] + Math.floor((Math.random() * maxGap) + 1));
}
//myDates now contains random consecutive integer timestamps in seconds
```

Comment: Would be nice if I could choose a start date/not precise down to second, but this is a great start. Thanks +1